# Count the total occurences for each day in given dates

Tags: count

I have this table and don't enough SQL to make a query to achieve the result shown in the image below.

```
CREATE TABLE myDates (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    startDate date NOT NULL,
    endDate date NOT NULL
);

insert into myDates(id, startDate, endDate)
values
(1, '2017-12-26', '2017-12-29'),
(2, '2017-12-29', '2017-12-29'),
(3, '2017-12-14', '2017-12-29'),
(4, '2017-12-18', '2017-12-21'),
(5, '2017-12-26', '2017-12-29'),
(6, '2017-12-28', '2017-12-29'),
(7, '2017-12-26', '2017-12-29'),
(8, '2017-12-25', '2017-12-27')
```

Look at all days between 'startDate' and 'endDate' and count the total of occurrences per day:

**Expected result**
[image]

**I just added this image** from an Excel File to illustrate better what I am trying to achieve. I am moving from excel to sql. Ignore weekends and 22/12 and 25/12.

[image]

Regrads,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: Must be both dates (start and end) included?

Comment: Can you provide your DBMS? (Note that the `sql` tag means the question involves the SQL language in general; for MS SQL Server, you should select the `sql-server` tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty "procedural" approach, as opposed to set-based / pure RDBMS, but it should work.  Basically you create a "frequency table" which tracks how many times your source table has a row that contains "a date", for each date from `min` to `max`.  Sample code built to follow yours (i.e. you've already created your `myDates` table and filled it with data).

```
CREATE TABLE #DateFrequency (theDate date, freq int);
--TRUNCATE TABLE #DateFrequency;

DECLARE @theDate date, @maxDate date;
SELECT @theDate = MIN(startDate), @maxDate = MAX(endDate)
    FROM myDates

WHILE (@theDate <= @maxDate)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #DateFrequency (theDate, freq)
    SELECT @theDate, COUNT(id)
    FROM myDates
    WHERE @theDate BETWEEN startDate AND endDate;

    SET @theDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @theDate);
END

SELECT * FROM #DateFrequency;
--DROP TABLE #DateFrequency;
```

Then do whatever you need to do with the data in #DateFrequency; make it a permanent table (instead of #temporary) if you need.

PS: read [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) by Aaron Bertrand about handling date ranges; it's not directly aimed at your issue because you (correctly) used the `Date` type instead of `DateTime`, but it's still what I consider mandatory reading if you're dealing with this kind of data and these kinds of queries.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a set-based approach that uses an Common Table Expression (CTE) to generate a quick Date Dimension table and then we use the CTE to group by date

The answer is the same as @nates

```
Declare @myDates TABLE  (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    startDate date NOT NULL,
    endDate date NOT NULL
);

insert into @myDates(id, startDate, endDate)
values
(1, '2017-12-26', '2017-12-29'),
(2, '2017-12-29', '2017-12-29'),
(3, '2017-12-14', '2017-12-29'),
(4, '2017-12-18', '2017-12-21'),
(5, '2017-12-26', '2017-12-29'),
(6, '2017-12-28', '2017-12-29'),
(7, '2017-12-26', '2017-12-29'),
(8, '2017-12-25', '2017-12-27')
;

WITH dates ([Date])
AS (
    SELECT convert(DATE, '2017-01-01') AS [Date] -- Put the start date here

    UNION ALL

    SELECT dateadd(day, 1, [Date])
    FROM dates
    WHERE [Date] <= '2020-12-31' -- Put the end date here 
    )
SELECT [Date]
    ,count(*)
FROM dates d
JOIN @myDates m ON d.[Date] >= m.startDate
    AND d.[Date] <= m.endDate
GROUP BY [Date]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767) -- Don't forget to use the maxrecursion option!
```

Comment: Note that you can limit the generation of the date dimension, using the minimum start date and maximum end date instead of hard-coded values. otherwise, beat me to it by that much. Here's a [SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/021176/2) to the version I was finishing up.

Comment: @RDFozz - yes, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: This is a cool alternative!  It's fun to find a really *good* use for a recursive CTE, because they're pretty _niche_ and occasionally a bit scary to the unfamiliar.  Nice one  =)

Comment: @NateJ - a little something to put in the old toolbag :)

Comment: @ScottHodgin interesting note, the min. value for `MAXRECURSION` seems to be just a bit below 1500.  This is directly related to the difference between your "start" date and "end" date -- `DATEDIFF(DAY, '20170101', '20201231')`.  Specifically, *that* plus 1 (1461 in this case).  For the curious!